# Boost date time conversion error

Tags: c++, datetime, boost

I installed boost from synaptic.

Now i need to convert date from/to string, but when I write code like below,

```
date dt{2018-9-14};

string str=to_simple_string(dt);

cout<<str<<endl;
```

it gives an error:

```
/usr/include/boost/date_time/date_formatting.hpp:44: undefined reference to `boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_short_string() const'
/usr/include/boost/date_time/date_formatting.hpp:49: undefined reference to `boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_long_string() const'
```

How can I solve this???

Answer (score 2):

As the other answer stated, the  constructor is wrong (use commas, or you'll simply say `2018-9-14` which is equal to `1995`).

Next, you forgot to link the boost_date_time library:

Starting from a completely new and fresh 16.04 machine:

```
apt update; apt install -yy build-essential libboost-all-dev
echo -e '#include <boost/date_time.hpp>\nint main(){std::cout<<boost::gregorian::to_simple_string({2018,9,14})<<std::endl;}' > test.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -lboost_date_time && ./a.out
```

Works and prints

```
2018-Sep-14
```

Teach a man how to fish: [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Show a man eating the fish:

[image]

Comment: "eating the fish" ftw, go @sehe :-)

Comment: #include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include "boost/date_time.hpp"
#include "boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::gregorian;


int main()
{
   date dt{2018,10,15};
   string str_date=to_simple_string(dt);
   
   cout<<str_date<<endl;

return 0;
}

Comment: You missed the point. I have you the linker option  for a reason. As well as a link to the [tag:c++-faq] answer

Answer (score 0):

Your initialization of dt looks suspicious. I think you want dt{2018, 9, 14} if you want 14th Septmber 2018.

A fuller version of your code might look like:

```
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  const boost::gregorian::date dt{2018, 9, 14};
  const std::string str = boost::gregorian::to_simple_string(dt);

  std::cout << str << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

which correctly produces

```
2018-Sep-14
```

as its output.

Comment: But,same error in my computer while executing your code. i am using boost 1.58 . ubuntu 16.04 machine. is there anything else to solve this problem????

Comment: Curious - I'm using a very similar system, with boost-1.62, and don't think these aspects of boost::date_time have changed much since version1.40 or earlier. My compile line is "g++ test.cpp -lboost_date_time -I/usr/include/boost". Perhaps you could give a bit more detail of your own code & compilation steps?

Comment: One thing worth checking with Ubuntu-16.04 is whether you've enabled C++11 support within the compiler - using the braced initializer syntax is a C++11 feature. You could try adding '-std=c++11' to your compiler options.

Comment: i am using netbeans for c++. i installed lib boost 1.58 from synaptic. all date time functionality i can use rather than conversion. is there any need to configure netbeans for boost. thank you very much brother.